# regex for a word in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dojo

regex for  a paragraph written and i  want to search for a word in it.

i tried using .search but i am not getting the right answer eg :-

Science (from Latin scientia, meaning "knowledge") is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe.[1] In an older and closely related meaning (found, for example, in Aristotle)

***in the above sentence if i have to find the word "knowledge". what regex can i use .***

Actually i have made a form in dojo :-

name : *text area*
address : *text area*
tele. no :*number txt area*

submit button

now when i click on the submit button. the name address and tele no. fields should automatically get filled in a letter which goes as follows :-

Dear [name] ,

This is to inform you that blah blah blah blah. you can contact the undersigned.
[tele no] ,[address]

1. i have made the form. now i am trying to match the label's inner html and the word in the brackets.if it is the same then the value has to get stroed in the letter. kindly  help to give a better idea

Comment: Where is the regEx you've tried? This explains regex in js Pretty well. http://bit.ly/VFFMeb

Comment: Your question is vague... finding the word "knowledge" is simple to do but appears pointless, as you have not said what you need to do once you've found it, which I am guessing will be a much more important part of your question.

Comment: i have written the entire question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2hNwL/1/

But as pointed by Ollie, this is pretty pointless. Considering you may want to replace the string knowledge, I have used replace function too:

```
var str = 'Science (from Latin scientia, meaning "knowledge") is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe.[1] In an older and closely related meaning (found, for example, in Aristotle)';

var match = str.match(/knowledge/gi);

if(match != null)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < match.length; i++)
        alert(match[i]);

    var replacedString = str.replace(/knowledge/gi,'egdelwonk');
    alert(replacedString);
}
```

Based on your edit, see my new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kPRDH/

```
var str = 'Dear [name] ,This is to inform you that blah blah blah blah. you can contact the undersigned. [tele no] ,[address]';


str = str.replace(/\[name\]/g,'TCM');
str = str.replace(/\[tele no\]/g,'9999999999');
str = str.replace(/\[address\]/g,'221B Bakers Street');

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following RegEx:

```
/knowledge/ig
```

I don't think you need a RegEx for this anyway:

```
string.indexOf('knowledge'); // Will give you the first index of the word
```